# How to turn the wheels on a robot that uses ros_control?

Tags: ros-melodic, mobile-robot, wheeled-robot, ros-control, gazebo-ros-control

I have made a robot with 4 wheels and it uses ros_control. At the moment I can use a python script to make it move forward and backward but I don't know how to make the wheels turn as it only has the `/command` topic which accepts a Float64 data input so no linear and angular axis inputs like `/cmd_vel` etc. Am I able to make the robot subscribe to another topic, if yes, how do I do that?

Github code for the robot: [here](https://github.com/balen-muon/first_robot).
The whole project can be launched using the following command if you want to run it on your own machine:

```
roslaunch ford_bot launch_all.launch
```

Some guidance on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Balen. Is that a simulated or a real robot?

Comment: @Robotawi It is a simulated robot in Gazebo at the moment but I want to make sure I get the foundational functions working then it will be translated into a real robot.

Comment: how does it move forward and backward if the wheels are not turning?

Comment: @jsotola , I meant that it doesn't turn left and right. The wheels do rotate though. Anyways thanks for the comment but I managed to fix the problem and I have posted the answer if you'd like to have a look it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to fix the issue. I removed the ros_control controllers I was using and replaced the control for the robot with the skid steer plugin which I found out about in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ad2jd8SCK-o) and now I can move my robot with the teleop keyboard node that's readily available to send messages on the `cmd_vel` topic which the robot is already subscribed to. The new code is available on my [GitHub](https://github.com/balen-muon/first_robot). The `roslaunch ford_bot launch_all.launch` command will launch the robot and gazebo etc. and then you can use the `rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py` command to control the robot.